# How can we get the details of percentage of flv video played by a user using php

Tags: php, video, video-streaming, html5-video

Is there any way to measure the duration for which the user watched the video...using php?

I have a web app for videos, here i want to check that for how many minutes the user has played the respective flash or wmv video files, so that i can keep track of it in my database.

Is there any flash player that provides this..through api or something..?

Comment: Is it youtube or something else? If it's youtube it's got javascript api for that.

Comment: Seeing as how PHP is server-side, and what you are attempting to do is client-side, the short answer is no. You need to look at client-side technologies to accomplish this.

Comment: You'll have to track the data using JavaScript and send it to your server for the PHP to do its magic.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're sending out 206 HTTP responses, you may be able to track it that way, or at least get a "general idea", by looking at the range.

http://benramsey.com/blog/2008/05/206-partial-content-and-range-requests/

This, coupled with the interface that they're watching the video with, will help give you an accurate assessment of what is going on.